# Application Registration Portal for Graph Api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, multi-tenant, azureportal

Im using Application Regristration Portal to get a token and access MS Graph Api.

When i register an app in Application Registration Portal i can see it in my tenan in Enterprise Application list. This works until 19/09/2018.

Today i register the app with the same account and i didnt see the app in my Azure Active Directory --> Enterprise Apps.

I have the old application that i register in Application Registration Portal and i see it in Enterprise Apps list but new applications not.

Comment: You mean apps.dev.microsoft.com? Did you sign in with your AAD account there when you registered the app?

Comment: Yes. In dev.microsoft.com i register the app with: admin@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com

Answer (score 1):

For now, the new v2 app cannot be seen in the Azure portal, and the new v1 app only can be seen in Application Registration Portal which you are explicitly marked as an owner of the application.

For the details about this, you could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison).

Comment: How can i mark explicitly my account as owner? Thank you

Comment: new v2 app is visible in Azure Portal AAD -->Enterprise apps

Comment: Have you authenticated against the new App ID yet? I don't believe it will show up until a user has authenticated from that tenant.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**

1. I register a new app in http://apps.dev.microsoft.com
2. I go Azure Active Directory --> Enterprise applications list --> **App does not appear**
3. I copy the application id in http://apps.dev.microsoft.com and paste it in my Sharepoint app for make a request with **POPUP login** **( without popup not work )**
4. I do login in this popup and send request for permission to AAD.
5. I go AAD --> Enterprise applications --> **I see my app in the list and i can grant permission**